# Json.NET deserializing object always shows null

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> not working .
```

Always getting null.

```
Json.NET deserializing object returns null.
```

Here is the code:

```
 JsonResult jsonresult = Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            User _contacts = new User();


           _contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonresult.Data.ToString());
```

In `jsonresult.Data.ToString()`:

```
{"recordsTotal":13,"recordsFiltered":13,"data":[{"Id":2,"Title":"Brajo testing","Type":null,"Description":null,"Importancy":null,"CreatedDate":"2017-03-16T14:31:04.41","Status":null,"Email":"+HNcbJGxLqAGmAQq9gOW1A==","Name":"Oliver Woodss"},{"Id":3,"Title":"udal testing","Type":null,"Description":null,"Importancy":null,"CreatedDate":"2017-03-16T14:31:41.253","Status":null,"Email":"+HNcbJGxLqAGmAQq9gOW1A==","Name":"Oliver Woodss"},
```

When i assign this comes null.

```
result = this.Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = _contacts }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Which value u r getting null ?? You need to assign like this recordsFiltered = _contacts.recordsTotal, _contacts.recordsTotal,...

Comment: In _contacts i am getting null

Comment: here is the model

Comment: public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserList = new List<User>();
    }
    public List<User> UserList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A User's username. eg: "sergiotapia, mrkibbles, matumbo"
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A User's name. eg: "Sergio Tapia, John Cosack, Lucy McMillan"
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("CreatedDate")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

}

Comment: ERROR ON responseResult

Comment: Is there any othermethod to send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

```
var response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
var responseResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>
                    (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

Then you can fetch data from responseResult with a dot operator.
```

Comment: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EmailTemplate.UI.Areas.Ticket.Models.User]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a

Comment: Path 'recordsTotal', line 1, position 16.

Comment: what should i do??

Comment: IS THERE ANY THING WRONG WITH MODEL

Comment: Check with this,  List<User> responseResult = (List<User>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response ), typeof(List<User>)); If u get error for Newtonsoft, then u need to add the reference using Nuget

Comment: ERROR ON re‌​sponse,TYPEOF

Comment: CANNOT CONVERT SYSYSTEM.NET.HTTP.

Comment: hOW DO I ASSIGN IN MODEL??